# ftp-proxy set up on ubuntu

Tags: proxy, ftp, sftp

I have a ftp service which i u se to backup several websites with the WPVivid plugin. Unfortunately this ftp server blocks the outgoing ip address from my hosting.

To solve this i am trying to get ftp-proxy running on a VPS. So the ftp traffic goes through the vps. The ip address of my vps is not blocked by the ftp server. I have read the man pages, but can not figure out how to connect to the ftp-proxy.

Suppose the ftp server is on ftp.server.com and credentials are user1 with password pass1. How do i put this in the .conf file of the ftp-proxy? And which ftp details do i enter in the ftp server details in the WPVivid plugin?